# How to play audio and wait to finish to countinue to play again?

Tags: android, audio, media-player

How to play audio and wait to finish to countinue to play again?? . In this i can play so many time :D

```
    ivSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", 1000).show();
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);

            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer
                        .setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.release();

                            };
                        });
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is working fine for every button click. If you wish the audio to be repeated automatically, use

```
 mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

If you wish that when Ist sound is completely played then, second one should start on a button click,
try disabling ur button click while the first sound is playing and then enable the click onCompleteListener... Some thing like this:

```
ivSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", 1000).show();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);
ivSelect.setClickable(false); //Disabling the button click
 mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Enable click on Audio completion

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            ivSelect.setClickable(true);

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: May be sorry for my english. But i Mean. When the button click and cick immediately again. Two media is playing. and it's not good. I want play when the fist audio is finish.I wan't play when the media is not playing :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the current playback to finish before starting the next one.

Comment: Then this is what you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#METADATA_KEY_DURATION